# Filtering entries by a date range

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to use the entries of this form to make spreadsheets for billing my clients.  I'd like to set a custom filter for each client so that on the day I need to bill them I can simply apply the preset filter and it will display a period of entries from, say, last monday through friday.  I typically will run this on Monday mornings, so I was trying to filter by "today" through "today" minus six days.  But, I can't figure out the syntax of how to write that in the advanced editor.

Answer (score 1):

The Advanced Filtering code I figured out approaches it a little backward from how I was thinking. This is the filter code that worked for me:

```
=Date.AddDays(7) >= "today"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be quite a challenge but here is what I came up with that worked the best for date ranges within a specific range:

=(Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(30) and Date >= DateTime.Today)

Simply adjust the "adddays" number by whatever you need.